# Asking about UK Short-term Visitor Visa Financial requirements for STUDENT

Tags: visas, uk, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds, algerian-citizens

i'm 20 years old, i am currently in my second year of study in the university in Algeria, i want to apply for General English courses in Liverpool school of English for 2 weeks so i need to apply for Short-term Student Visa but i have problem in financial requirements i need to seek advice for you please:

- I have a bank account in my name with (1500£) plus fees of
  accomondation and application fees.
- My mother is a teacher for 3 years (200£ per month) and she has only
  savings account she has no bank account.
- My father is a retired teacher for more than 7 years (250£ per month)
  and he has no bank account or any account only post office account
  from where he get paid.
- My brother has a professional commercial Bank account in his name he
  was receiving a lots of money on it, he has a commercial register and
  everything but right now he has no money in his account for a bout 5
  months he didn't received money on it.

***My questions is :***
what should I put in my application for financial documents, should I put payslips for my parents or open bank accounts for them and make them my official sponsor, or should I extract my money from my bank account and put it in my brother's account and make him my sponsor or what to do please?

Thank you for advance!

Comment: @DavidRicherby Thank you for your comment, yes but in my case i want to know what bank statements are better to use my brother's or parents

Comment: @Steven Paul How much are you planning to spend on attending this short course? Liverpool is not an expensive area of the UK, the language school website indicates accommodation is available at around £135 pw. https://www.lse.uk.net/accommodation/ Why do you need a sponsor? On the face of it you have sufficient resources for a 2 week visit yourself, providing you can prove the source of your savings

Comment: A good general principle is to keep your application as simple and direct as possible. Even if you write a clear explanation of a transfer, it may get missed. An unexplained money transfer will be presumed to be hiding something.

Comment: @Traveller thanks for your help but evidence of the funds what should i say to the clearance-maker  cause these money all are from my savings ( i still didn't put the money on my bank account i have it as cash at home, can i give it to my brother and he put it in his account and then send it to my bank account through his, and i put the transfer statement as evidence for my moeny ?) thanks for advance!

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan thanks for your help, if i put my bank account statement in my application and i'm a  student, i don't have an evidence from where i got the funds, but i my brother transfer the money from his account to mine, it will be accepted as funds evidence?

Comment: @Steven Paul Unfortunately there’s no easy way to deposit cash into your or your brother’s account shortly before applying for a visa without it being seen as ‘funds parking’ by the ECO. Giving it to your brother to send back to you makes no sense either - you can’t get away from needing to explain the source.

Comment: Important information: When the application says 'bank account' that includes savings accounts and post office accounts.

Comment: Does **your** bank account have enough money to pay for the costs of your trip? And if not, where is the money coming from?

Comment: @Traveller i can wait up to 3 months before submitting my application, means right now i have 3 months before my application what can i do with this cash to make it genuine financial evidence or how much i should wait so it will make sense to the clearence-maker ?

Comment: @DJClayworth i have 1500£in cash i have bank account in my name and my parents have post office account where they get paid, can i use their payslips and post office account statements and make them sponsor me? or what is the best solution for me right now?

Comment: @DJClayworth i have enough money in my bank account but i'm student i don't have any evidence for the funds stored in my bank account the only evidence that i have is that those money are from my own savings every month for the pas 2 years.

Comment: When you say the money is 'from your savings over 2 years', where were you keeping those savings for the two years?

Comment: @Steven Paul Can you elaborate on how you got your  ‘savings’? Earnings from a part-time job? Gift from relative or friend? Surplus from monthly allowance? Sale of personal possessions? Whatever the source, you’ll need to prove it

Comment: @DJClayworth i was keep it as cash at home i didn't put it in my bank account which i created it last month (january 2019)

Comment: I think we have enough information to answer this question.

Comment: @Traveller i was getting money as gift from my father every month and from selling some of my personal stuffs, i don't now to make evidence for this earning ??

Comment: @DJClayworth what is last conclusion what i can do in this situation for the financial evidence?

Answer (score 2):

I think we can now answer this question. Allow me to summarize your situation:

1. You have a bank account which has enough money in it to fund your trip.
2. However this bank account has only been in existence for a month.
3. Most of the money in it was recently depositied and you say it came from your savings, which were in cash and you have no record of your finances before that.
4. You have no other records of your income or expenditure before the account was opened.
5. You have various other relatives who also have either very little money or no financial records.

**Will my application be successful based on this information?**

In my opinion (and it is only my opinion) it will not. One of the requirements is that you demonstrate a) that you have sufficient funds for your visit b) that the funds are really yours c) your financial circumstances are such that it is reasonable to spend the amount of money you want to spend on a trip to the UK.

You cannot provide evidence to backup either b or c. This is almost certainly going to result in your application being rejected.

**What about if I get someone else to sponsor me?**

No amount of transferring money from you to someone else and getting them to sponsor you is going to rescue this. Your relatives do not appear to have well-documented finances (a sponsor needs to be able to demonstrate that they have the money to pay you, and that they can afford to do it, just like you would if you were paying for yourself). Even if you had a relative who could afford this, your own lack of financial records are going to count against you.

**How can I get to visit the UK?**

Keep the bank account you have open, and start using it for your financial transactions. When you have done this for a year or so, you will have built up enough of a picture to satisfy the visa officers. Keep whatever savings you have in a savings account, so that you have a record of them. Then consider applying in a year's time.

Comment: Thank you very much sir this really helped me, but one more question, i was with my brother right now he told me that his bank account is old and he was receiving money from many companies (private companies, schools, universities...), he told me that the last payment he got was of 2000 pounds  on december 31th, his account now is 0 pound balance but he'll receive an amount of 3000 pounds soon from work with an government agency, he has his documents of his private bussiness means all documents everything legal and last transaction on his bank account was in december 2018, he can sponsors me?

Comment: That's completely different from what you said about him in the question.

Comment: my brother will receive about 3200 pounds this month, what if i wait for 3 months while he's receiving money in his bank account and he'll give me his work documents and payment evidence and companies bills and everything, it will work?

Comment: yes sir i was totally wrong cause i didn't know that until i met him i was very surprised he worked with many companies private and government companies and he's receiving a lot of funds in his account !

Comment: You wrote the question three hours ago, and now you are changing the story completely.

Comment: i'm sorry sir but i didn't know the truth about my brother's bank account cause he's working and living far from me i went to him and asked him about that he gave all the correct informations, really sorry about that.

Comment: I would suggest asking a new question.

Comment: @StevenPaul: What on earth does "until I met him" mean for someone you claim is **your brother**?

Comment: @HenningMakholm "met" probably means "had a face-to-face conversation with" in this context.